# How to get value of atribute SRC of <source/> HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

**THE HTML CODE**

```
 <video>
     <source id="sourceVideo" type="video/mp4" src="//servertfs:3635/conference.mp4"/>
 </video>

$(document).ready(function () {
     debugger;
     var flowplayer = $("#sourceVideo");
});
```

I tried to reference with jquery using the id `sourceVideo` but i couldnt find the `src` attribute is there any easy way, or tip?

Thanks

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, I suggest to explain clearly, what differs significantly in yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attr()` function to get the value of attributes from a jQuery object:

```
 var source = flowplayer.attr("src");
```